# Any alternative to curl_exec()?

Tags: php, post, curl, licensing, callback

I am trying to make a sort of license checking script, but as not all hosts allow `curl_exec`, I would like to know, if there is any alternative way of making a call-back?

This is how I do it with curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."/my_script.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $info);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `file_get_contents()` with URLs:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

This may be disabled, though, with just a simple INI option `allow_url_fopen`.

Alternatively, you may use `fsockopen()`, which should be available on most systems.

With `fsockopen()` you can open a socket to a HTTP server, then communicate using standard `fwrite()` and `fread()`. The downside is that you must write HTTP request headers by yourself, and you must also parse HTTP response headers too. If you look at `fsockopen()` on PHP's manual, you can see plenty of examples: https://www.php.net/fsockopen

My suggestion is to use cURL as primary option, file_get_contents() as secondary (if `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` returns a positive result) and implement solutions like `fsockopen()` as fallback.

Comment: Cheers! I'll see if I am able to make it do want I want :).

Comment: Take a look at this code I wrote: http://pastie.org/2476499 It's pretty old (Finder dates it back to 2007), so you may want to adjust it, for example removing the @ and using other error reporting ways, like exceptions (in 2007, everybody - including me - used to write PHP code in a different way :). But you may get an idea... Writing HTTP headers is not hard, eventually: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Example_session

Answer (score 2):

You could switch [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), but that's probably disabled as well.

Alternatively, use the [HTTP stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php). To configure a POST request, you'll need to set up your own [HTTP context](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Comment: I don't know anything about HTTP stream wrappers or HTTP context, is it normally possible to use it from like a regular shared hosting provider? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @MrE It's enabled by default, so it should be available on must hosting providers. However, bear in mind that a paranoid hosting provider who has disabled curl for security reasons will almost definitely disable stream wrappers too.